# On bijectivity of the functor $\mathsf{Set}\to\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb R}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

The hom-functor gives a (contravariant) functor $\mathsf{Set}\to\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb R}$ (where $\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb R}$ is the category of associative and commutative $\mathbb R$-algebras with identity wherein morphisms preserve identities) like so: Any function $p\colon X\to Y$ gets mapped to $p^*\colon\mathbb R^Y\to\mathbb R^X$ where $p^*$ is given by $p^*(f) = f\circ p$.

My question is twofold:

1. (Surjectivity). If $\rho\colon\mathbb R^Y\to\mathbb R^X$ is an (identity-preserving)  algebra homomorphism, is it induced by some map $p\colon X\to Y$ so that $\rho = p^*$?
2. (Injectivity). If $p^* = q^*$ for $p, q\colon X\to Y$, can I conclude that $p = q$?

Answer (score 3):

The functor is not bijective with the usual meaning of that word (a functor is bijective when it is bijective on morphisms and on objects). What you are actually asking is if the functor $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{CAlg}_{\mathbb{R}}$, $X \mapsto \mathbb{R}^X$ is [full](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+functor) (surjective on hom-sets) and [faithful](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/faithful+functor) (injective on hom-sets).

Since $\mathbb{R}^X \cong \prod_{x \in X} \mathbb{R}$ is a product, it suffices to consider the case $X = \{\star\}$. Let me rename $Y$ to $X$. For $x \in X$ we have the evaluation homomorphism $\mathrm{ev}_x : \mathbb{R}^X \to X$ defined by $\mathrm{ev}_x(a):=a(x)$. The question then is just:

- Faithfulness: If $x,x' \in X$ satisfy $\mathrm{ev}_x = \mathrm{ev}_{x'} : \mathbb{R}^X \to \mathbb{R}$, do we have $x=x'$?
- Fullness: If $f : \mathbb{R}^X \to \mathbb{R}$ is an algebra homomorphism, is there some $x \in X$ with $f = \mathrm{ev}_x$?

Faithfulness is easy. Consider the element $\delta_x \in \mathbb{R}^X$ defined by $\delta_x(x') := \delta_{x,x'}$. Then $1 = \mathrm{ev}_x(\delta_x) = \mathrm{ev}_{x'}(\delta_x) = \delta_{x,x'}$, hence $x=x'$.

Fullness is much more interesting when $X$ is infinite (the finite case is easy). Notice that an algebra homomorphism $f : \mathbb{R}^{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the same as a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{X}$ with $\mathbb{R}^{X} / \mathfrak{m} \cong \mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras. The maximal ideals are known, they correspond to the [ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $X$ (see [SE/3285960](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285960) for example). If $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $X$, then
$$\mathfrak{m} := \{a \in \mathbb{R}^X : \{x \in X : a(x) = 0\} \in \mathcal{U}\}$$
is the corresponding maximal ideal. If $\mathcal{U} = [x]$ is a principal filter, then $\mathfrak{m} = \{a \in \mathbb{R}^X : a(x)=0\}$, and this is exactly what we want to show. We need to use $\mathbb{R}^X / \mathfrak{m} \cong \mathbb{R}$ to deduce that $\mathcal{U}$ is principal.

The field $\mathbb{R}^X / \mathfrak{m}$ is an [ultrapower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) of $\mathbb{R}$. In the special case $X = \mathbb{N}$, when $\mathcal{U}$ does not contain any finite set, $\mathbb{R}^X / \mathfrak{m}$ is (one version of) the field of [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number), which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. I strongly believe that a similar argument works in the general case, but I can't complete it at the moment ...

I am not sure if it helps here, but notice that $\mathbb{R}^X = C(X)$ if we view $X$ as a discrete topological space. If $X$ is a *compact* space, then it is well-known that all maximal ideals of $C(X)$ have the form $\{a : a(x)=0\}$ for some $x \in X$ (this is the "easy" part of Gelfand duality). But we can apply this here only when $X$ is finite, and since $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact we cannot extend functions to $\beta X$, and since the functions don't necessary vanish at $\infty$ we cannot extend them to $X^+$ either ...

Comment: In fact, it is possible to have a non-principal ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if measurable cardinals exist!

Comment: Oh my god ... no wonder that I couldn't finish it. Thanks!